# How do I update my repository to the main branch?

Tags: git, github, repository, branch

I have cloned the main branch and have not made any changes since. However my team member has pushed some changes of his own to the main branch and before I start making changes myself I would like to update my repository and pull from the main branch but have gotten unmerged error conflicts. Can anyone help with the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do one of the following:

1. delete the local directory and clone it again (as you described you did not modify any file).
2. execute the following command to return to the last commit you had in your branch.

   ```
   git clean -df && git checkout -- .
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't made any changes, you should be able to `git pull` without encountering conflicts. If you have made changes and want to just revert your local repository, you can try

```
git stash
git stash drop
```

These commands undo all your local changes.

Comment: git stash doesn't work for me. Some reason I am seeing errors likes .classpath needs merge

Comment: This usually means that you have committed changes on your local branch that conflict with the remote branch. You have to do a merge then, try `git mergetool`. If you don't want to populate your local changes, the easiest method is possibly to just clone the repository again.